# How did Boris Johnson chair the cabinet meetings while he has COVID-19?

Tags: united-kingdom, covid-19, prime-minister, cabinet, boris-johnson

I didn't follow the UK news closely, so please enlighten me on how cabinet meetings were conducted by Boris Johnson while he has COVID-19. All I've read on this [is that](https://www.bbc.com/news/uk-52177125):

> Prime Minister Boris Johnson has been admitted to hospital for tests, 10 days after testing positive for coronavirus, Downing Street has said.
>
> He was taken to a London hospital on Sunday evening with "persistent symptoms" - including a temperature.
>
> It is said to be a "precautionary step" taken on the advice of his doctor.
>
> The prime minister remains in charge of the government, but **the foreign secretary is expected to chair a coronavirus meeting on Monday morning**. [...]
>
> Mr Johnson has worked from home since it was announced that he had tested positive for coronavirus on 27 March.

So did BoJo chair the prior meetings via videconferencing, but this is no longer possible from a hospital setting (as opposed to his home)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Prime Minister has been chairing meetings via videoconference, specifically using Zoom ([BBC News](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/technology-52126534?intlink_from_url=https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/topics/c8nq32jw8r1t/boris-johnson&link_location=live-reporting-correspondent)).

It is being reported this evening (by [ITV News](https://twitter.com/ShehabKhan/status/1246900785876799493) among others) that tomorrow's COVID-19 meeting will be chaired by Dominic Raab, the First Secretary of State.

Comment: Given the "dismal security" criticism leveled at Zoom (in the article you linked), I wonder why he can't use that from a hospital...

Comment: @Fizz latest reports [suggest](https://www.businessinsider.com/coronavirus-boris-johnson-admitted-hospital-coronavirus-symptoms-tests-aides-worried-2020-4?r=US&IR=T) he's being given oxygen treatment - unlikely to be conducive to chairing a video conference!